# Why doesn't Reflections.getFieldsAnnotatedWith() return any fields?

Tags: java, unit-testing, reflection, annotations, reflections

I'm running into a problem with [Reflections](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/). 
I'm trying to get a `Set` of fields with `Reflections#getFieldsAnnotatedWith` method but when I run a unit test, it return nothing, can anybody tell me why? (*I'm using the IntelliJ IDE*)

Here are the classes I'm using, it's very basic.

```
//The test class run with junit

public class ReflectionTestingTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Reflections ref = new Reflections(AnnotatedClass.class);
        assertEquals(2, ref.getFieldsAnnotatedWith(TestAnnotation.class).size());
        Set<Field> fields = ref.getFieldsAnnotatedWith(TestAnnotation.class);
    }
}

//The class with the annotated fields I want to have in my Set.

public class AnnotatedClass {

    @TestAnnotation
    public int annotatedField1 = 123;

    @TestAnnotation
    public String annotatedField2 = "roar";
}

//And the @interface itself

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface TestAnnotation {}
```

The test fails with the following message:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :2
Actual   :0
```

Comment: The response is correct - there _are_ no fields annotated `@TestAnnotation` in the class you're asking about.

Comment: @Ian Roberts My bad, I've badly copy-pasted and then edited the code here in stackoverflow. Assume that the annotations were correct. I've updated the sample code to reflect the issue properly now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `AnnotatedClass` should have the fields annotated with `@TestAnnotation`. Your code will return **2** then.

```
public class AnnotatedClass {

    @TestAnnotation
    public int annotatedField1 = 123;

    @TestAnnotation
    public String annotatedField2 = "roar";

}
```

Now, to query fields and methods, you need to specify the scanner while creating a `Reflections` object. Moreover, the usage of `Reflections` should be:

```
Reflections ref = new Reflections("<specify package name here>", new FieldAnnotationsScanner());
```

Comment: My bad, I've badly copy-pasted and then edited the code here in stackoverflow. Assume that the annotations were correct. I've updated the sample code to reflect the issue properly now